# YA book about a girl and guy that try to change the future

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I'm looking for a YA book about a girl and guy. The girl lives on the water and she meets a new boy, whose name starts with a 'T.' She figures out that he is from the future and he has been sent to Earth to try to change it. She also has a boy best friend who is in love with her. Her boy best friend will discover a comet in the future that will do something. It's very heavily space-themed and contains space vocabulary.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?